# How to make Search data using Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i am a beginner of spring boot framework.i want to work with search records using spring boot application. my index.html is loaded successfully when i enter the employee id on the employee id textbox and click search button relevant employee name  result want to  display the below textbox.but i don't know how to pass it .what i tired so so i attached below.

**index.html**

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/search}" th:object="${employee}" method="post">

      
        <div alight="left">
            <tr>
                <label class="form-label" >Employee ID</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee ID" />
                </td>
            </tr>
         </div>   

            <br>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Search</button> </td>
            </tr>
            
            
            <div alight="left">
            <tr>
                <label class="form-label" >Employee Name</label>
                <td>
                  
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{ename}" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee Name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
         </div>   
    </form>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
    
     @Autowired
        private EmployeeService service;

    

        @GetMapping("/")
        public String add(Model model) {
            List<Employee> listemployee = service.listAll();
          //  model.addAttribute("listemployee", listemployee);
            model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
            return "index";
        }

        
        @RequestMapping("/search/{id}")
        public ModelAndView showSearchEmployeePage(@PathVariable(name = "id") int id) {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("new");
            Employee emp = service.get(id);
            mav.addObject("employee", emp);
            return mav;
            
        }
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity

    public class Employee {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String ename;
        private int mobile;
        private int salary;
    
        
        
        public Employee() {
            
        
        }
    
    
    
        public Employee(Long id, String ename, int mobile, int salary) {
            
            this.id = id;
            this.ename = ename;
            this.mobile = mobile;
            this.salary = salary;
        }
    
    
    
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
    
    
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
    
    
        public String getEname() {
            return ename;
        }
    
    
    
        public void setEname(String ename) {
            this.ename = ename;
        }
    
    
    
        public int getMobile() {
            return mobile;
        }
    
    
    
        public void setMobile(int mobile) {
            this.mobile = mobile;
        }
    
    
    
        public int getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }
    
    
    
        public void setSalary(int salary) {
            this.salary = salary;
        }
    
    
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employee [id=" + id + ", ename=" + ename + ", mobile=" + mobile + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
        }
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easiest to create a [dedicated form data object](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/):

```
public class EmployeeSearchFormData {
  private long employeeId;
  // getter and setter
}
```

In the controller:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
    
     @Autowired
     private EmployeeService service;

     @GetMapping("/")
     public String add(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("employeeSearchFormData", new EmployeeSearchFormData());
       return "index";
     }

        
     @PostMapping("/search")
     public String doSearchEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employeeSearchFormData") EmployeeSearchFormData formData, Model model) {
            Employee emp = service.get(formData.getEmployeeId());
            model.addAttribute("employee", emp);
            return "index";            
     }
}
```

Thymeleaf template:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/search}" th:object="${employeeSearchFormData}" method="post">

      
        <div alight="left">
            <tr>
                <label class="form-label" >Employee ID</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{employeeId}" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee ID" />
                </td>
            </tr>
         </div>   

            <br>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Search</button> </td>
            </tr>
            
            
            <div alight="left">
            <tr>
                <label class="form-label" >Employee Name</label>
                <td>
                  
                    <input type="text" th:field="${employee.ename}" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee Name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
         </div>   
    </form>
```

Note the use of `th:field="${employee.ename}"` and not use `*{...}`. I also removed the hidden field as it does not seem needed to have it to me.

As an alternative, you can have the `@PostMapping` redirect to `/employee/<id>` if there is an endpoint available like that:

```
@PostMapping("/search")
     public String doSearchEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employeeSearchFormData") EmployeeSearchFormData formData) {
            return "redirect:/employee/" + formData.getEmployeeId();            
     }
```

Comment: thank you for your kind help. i have another doubt you must clear sir. how to join to tables using spring boot.